# Как менять цвет уравнения линии тренда в xlsxWriter

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Подскажите, пожалуйста! Как можно менять цвет уравнении линии тренда?
В одном графике строю две линии тренда и нужно как то их различать.

Этот код добавляет данные в excel файл и строит график зависимости переменных со степенной функцией. 
Данные можно взять здесь:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MmUK1og3cELJ1LBdkwYcQS4HVtJl5_Ft/view?usp=sharing

Благодарю за любую помощь!

```
import pandas as pd

resData = pd.read_excel("resData.xlsx")
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('result'+'.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
sheet_name = 'sheet1'
resData.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name, index=False)

workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets[sheet_name]

chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'scatter'})
max_row = len(resData)
for i in range(len(resData.columns)-1):
    if i==0:
        trendcol="blue"
    else:trendcol="red"

    col = i + 1
    chart.add_series({
        'name':       [sheet_name, 0, col],
        'categories': [sheet_name, 1, 0, max_row, 0],
        'values':     [sheet_name, 1, col, max_row, col],
        'marker':     {'type': 'diamond', 'size': 8},
        'trendline': {'type': 'power', 'display_equation':True,#display_equation задает уравнение линии тренда 
        'line': {'color': trendcol,'width': 2,}}
    })
chart.set_x_axis({'name': 'X'})
chart.set_y_axis({'name': 'Y'})
worksheet.insert_chart('E8', chart,  {'x_scale': 1.5, 'y_scale': 2})

writer.save()
```

[image: Как линии отличаются так и так и уравнении нужно делать разными]

Comment: Не знаю как это сделать в Excel (xlsxWriter, openpyxl, etc.), но можно попробовать [самому посчитать тренд](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32121877/how-do-i-replicate-excels-power-trendline-in-python) и нарисовать в matplotlib

Comment: Спасибо большое! Наверное так и сделаю.